# REST API controller successfully creates a resource but returns 406 Not Acceptable

Tags: rest, asp.net-core

I have a *RESTful* API that when receiving a valid POST request, creates a resource on a repository (database) and returns the newly created object in JSON or XML with a HTTP 201 Created response header.

So I have configured my API to return HTTP 406 Not Acceptable when the consumer specifies an unknown response media type like so:

```cs
services.AddControllers(configure => configure.ReturnHttpNotAcceptable = true)
    .AddNewtonsoftJson(setup =>
    {
        setup.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();
    })
    .AddXmlDataContractSerializerFormatters()
```

This is my controller:

```cs
[ApiController]
[Route("api/v1/users")]
[Produces("application/json", "text/json", "application/xml", "text/xml")]
[ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status406NotAcceptable)]
public class UsersController : ControllerBase
{
    // [...]

    [HttpGet("{userId}", Name = "GetUser")]
    [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status200OK)]
    [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status404NotFound)]
    public ActionResult<User> GetUser(int userId)
    {
        var user = _repository.GetUser(userId);

        return user == null
            ? NotFound()
            : Ok(_mapper.Map<User>(user));
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status201Created)]
    [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status303SeeOther)]
    [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status400BadRequest)]
    [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status422UnprocessableEntity)]
    public ActionResult<User> CreateUser(UserForCreation userForCreation)
    {
        var existingUser = _repository.GetUser(userForCreation.Email);
        if (existingUser != null)
        {
            return this.SeeOther("GetUser", new { userId = existingUser.Id });
        }

        var user = _mapper.Map<DataModel.User>(userForCreation);
        _repository.AddUser(user);
        _repository.Save();

        var userToReturn = _mapper.Map<User>(user);

        return CreatedAtRoute("GetUser", new
        {
            userId = userToReturn.Id
        }, userToReturn);
    }
}
```

So, let's say I send a request with an accept header like `accept: text/plain`; until here my resource is created on the repository, but then when I get to the `CreatedAtRoute()` call, ASP returns the so called HTTP 406 status code.

I understand why this is happening, what I want to know is how (if possible) to tell ASP to return HTTP 406 before calling `CreateUser()` of before creating the resource on the repository.

Comment: Did you return 406 when you called CreatedAtRoute Api?

Comment: @Chaodeng yes, ASP returns 406 when calling `CreatedAtRoute`.